# Is there a `numpy.minimum` equivalent in GSL?

Tags: c++, numpy, gsl

I'm working on porting a complex data analysis routine I "prototyped" in Python to C++.  I used Numpy extensively throughout the Python code.  I'm looking at employing the GSL in the C++ port since it implements all of the various numerical routines I require (whereas Armadillo, Eigen, etc. only have a subset of what I need, though their APIs are closer to what I am looking for).

Is there an equivalent to `numpy.minimum` in the GSL (i.e., element-wise minimum of two matrices)?  This is just one example of the abstractions from Numpy that I am looking for.  Do things like this simply have to be reimplemented manually when using the GSL?  I note that the GSL provides for things like:

`double gsl_matrix_min (const gsl_matrix * m)`

But that simply provides the minimum value of the entire matrix.  Regardless of element-wise comparisons, it doesn't even seem possible to report the minimum along a particular axis of a single matrix using the GSL.  That surprises me.

Are my expectations misplaced?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an element-wise minimum easily in Armadillo, via the [find()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find) and [.elem()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) functions:

```
mat A; A.randu(5,5);
mat B; B.randu(5,5);

umat indices = find(B < A);

mat C = A;
C.elem(indices) = B.elem(indices);
```

For other functions that are not present in Armadillo, it might be possible to  interface Armadillo matrices with GSL functions, through the [.memptr()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#memptr) function.

Comment: As I noted, neither Armadillo nor Eigen have all of the features I need.  I did play with Eigen (similar to Armadillo, I would think) and it was very easy to get the reductions I need.  However, I'll need GSL for the balance.  I will take a look at .memptr() and report back.

Comment: Followed your link.  This definitely applies to me!  "**Obtain a raw pointer to the memory used for storing elements. Not recommended for use unless you know what you're doing!**"